# PHP classes and includes

Tags: php, pdo

Here is my dilemma, i am trying to start migrating my php to more of an object based code vs the old style as well as from mysqli to pdo. But as i do this i start running into some issues specially with class's and dependency's.

So for example i have one file called `pdo_connection.php` which holds my database connection info.

```
<?php
define("DSN", "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=user_info");
define("USERNAME", "root");  
define("PASSWORD", "password");  
$options = array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => TRUE);

try {
    $conn = new PDO(DSN,USERNAME,PASSWORD , $options);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    Echo "Folowing Problem: ".$ex->getMessage();
    exit();
}
```

now i have a file called pdo_user which is going to hold a class and functions which will handle the actual mysql queries.

```
//    include_once 'pdo_connection.php';
class data_user
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
        include_once 'pdo_connection.php';
    }       
    // Validate User Login        
    public function val_login($user, $passwd) 
    {
        //include_once 'pdo_connection.php';
        $sel = "CALL `user_info`.`sp_user_login`('$user', '$passwd')";
        $res = $conn->query($sel);
        while ($row = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            return($row);
        }
    }
}
```

when i call the function i get an error evertime if the include_once 'pdo_connection.php' is not inside the public function val_login.
I tried it putting in in the __construct or all the way on top, it always complains about `Undefined variable: conn in /var/www/html/mysql_pdo/pdo_user.php on line 27`

Simple fix is to place it inside the public function `val_login` but i can see thats the best way that it has to be loaded every time the function is called.

So hopefully someone can tell me what i am missing and how i can load things like conn once and all function can access.

Comment: Instead you should `include_once 'pdo_connection.php';` on bootstrap, and dependency inject `$conn` into the `data_user` constructor, then set to `$this->conn`, so methods have scope.

Comment: Really, if you're going to refactor your app, you might be better off implementing an ORM such as Doctrine. A little more work up front but less headache in the long run.

Comment: ok, i want to stay away from a ORM if posible. so where and how would i include_once and what else would i need to change ?

Comment: In mysqli_ land, you guys like to use `while` loops to fetch each result. In PDO land, just use  [PDOStatement::fetch](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)
 or [PDOStatement::fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) (no while loop needed).

Comment: Why do you catch the exception just to print its message and exit? Doesn't the default PHP exception handler do that anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is because of [variable scoping](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Let's look at your functions in isolation, and move the contents of `pdo_connection.php` into the `__construct` method just because it will highlight the problem better:

```
public function __construct() 
{
    define("DSN", "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=user_info");
    define("USERNAME", "root");  
    define("PASSWORD", "password");  
    $options = array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => TRUE);

    try {
        $conn = new PDO(DSN,USERNAME,PASSWORD , $options);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        Echo "Folowing Problem: ".$ex->getMessage();
        exit();
    }
}       

public function val_login($user, $passwd) 
{
    $sel = "CALL `user_info`.`sp_user_login`('$user', '$passwd')";
    $res = $conn->query($sel);
    while ($row = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        return($row);
    }
}
```

In your constructor, you are creating a *local* variable named `$conn`. Once the constructor method finishes, control returns back to the calling context and the `$conn` variable *disappears*. Its scope is only valid from within the `__construct` method.

If you want that connection variable to have a longer lifetime, the only real good option you have (since constructors cannot return values) is to store that variable as a [class property](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php). Once you do that, the lifetime of that property will be the same as the lifetime of the class instance itself:

```
class data_user
{
    // This just defines the property
    protected $conn;

    public function __construct() 
    {
        define("DSN", "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=user_info");
        define("USERNAME", "root");  
        define("PASSWORD", "password");  
        $options = array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => TRUE);

        try {
            // This is setting the property
            $this->conn = new PDO(DSN,USERNAME,PASSWORD , $options);
            $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            Echo "Folowing Problem: ".$ex->getMessage();
            exit();
        }
    }       

    public function val_login($user, $passwd) 
    {
        $sel = "CALL `user_info`.`sp_user_login`('$user', '$passwd')";
        // This is now accessing the class property and not a local variable
        // that is undefined.
        $res = $this->conn->query($sel);
        while ($row = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            return($row);
        }
    }
}
```

I would also explicitly advise *not* to include other files from within a class constructor. Consider this usage instead:

```
define("DSN", "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=user_info");
define("USERNAME", "root");  
define("PASSWORD", "password");  
$options = array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => TRUE);

try {
    $conn = new PDO(DSN,USERNAME,PASSWORD , $options);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    Echo "Folowing Problem: ".$ex->getMessage();
    exit();
}

$data_user = new data_user($conn);
$another_object = new another_object($conn);
```

This would change your `data_user` constructor to look like this:

```
public function __construct($conn) 
{
    $this->conn = $conn;
}
```

Which is simpler, allows you to re-use the same `$conn` object between other objects that may need a database connection, and avoids [doing work](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-constructor-does-real-work/) in your object constructor. It also [separates the concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) out of your `data_user` class so that it is much easier conceptually, since that class has no real reason to know about *how* to connect to your database. It just needs to know the connection itself.

Comment: ok it looks all great but i am a bit confused, i dont want to stick the Conn setup in every construct of any class i will have which needs a data connection. So idealy i want to have a data connection file and the have all my classes access the connection, hope that makes sense

Comment: @NoSoup4you I added a final example towards the end which is the approach I would use. Set up the connection outside the class, and then pass it in as a _dependency_ of the object. You can then still use that very same variable to pass to other objects without having to reconstruct another connection object. If you `include` the `pdo_connection` file multiple times, you will create multiple connections to your database which isn't good.

Comment: Also, another comment, if you `include_once` (as you are in your question), then the `$conn` variable will only ever be available _once_, ie if you try to `include_once` again, the file will not be interpreted at all and the variable _will not exist_ in the same scope.

Answer (score 2):

You may have a few issues going on. I tried to provide a couple of solutions.

First, you may want to look at PSR4 autoloading and namespaces. File classes are 'automagically' loaded from the directories given their naming structure. I was amazed once I figured out the autoloading capabilities. Also, you can register your own custom autoloaders in PHP (http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php). The idea is that if a class's name can be parsed to reference the class's file, then it can be autoloaded. No more include_once, require_once...

Second, you may want to read about dependency injection. Objects (in this case dependencies) are injected into other objects, typically in their __construct() method.

In simplest terms, I would alter your class to this:

```
<?php

namespace Data;

class User
{
    /**
     * The PDO connection
     */
    private $conn;

    /**
     * This receives the connection using dependency injection.
     * @param \PDO $conn     The connection.
     * @return null
     */
    public function __construct(\PDO $conn) 
    {
        $this -> conn = $conn;
    }

    // Validate User Login        
    public function valLogin($user, $passwd) 
    {
        $sel = "CALL `user_info`.`sp_user_login`('$user', '$passwd')";
        $res = $this -> conn ->query($sel);
        while ($row = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            return($row);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you might use it like this:

```
<?php
define("DSN", "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=user_info");
define("USERNAME", "root");  
define("PASSWORD", "password");  
$options = array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => TRUE);

try {
    $conn = new PDO(DSN,USERNAME,PASSWORD , $options);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    Echo "Folowing Problem: ".$ex->getMessage();
    exit();
}

// The connection is injected into the constructor.
$dataUser = new Data\User($conn);
$userRow = $dataUser -> valLogin($user, $passwd);
```

Hope this helps? If you have more questions please reply.

The other option would be to make the $conn global, which isn't a recommended approach.

One more option would be to create a class that receives the $connection and sets a static property. This isn't the best approach, but better then a global $conn variable.

```
class Connection
{
    public static $connection;

    public function __construct(\PDO $conn)
    {
        self::$connection = $conn;
    }
}
```

Then your val_login method would look like this:

```
    // Validate User Login        
    public function val_login($user, $passwd) 
    {
        $sel = "CALL `user_info`.`sp_user_login`('$user', '$passwd')";
        $res = Connection::$connection ->query($sel);
        while ($row = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            return($row);
        }
    }
```